# How to scrape what is heading of a h1 tag using golang?

Tags: go, web-scraping

Suppose this is a h1 tag

```
<h1>FindMe</h1>
```

in a huge webpage with many other h1 tags, but this is the first h1 tag. So I am using the net/html package and I am searching for the first StartTagToken, after my program has found the token, how do I get what is written inside the heading i.e. FindMe in this case.

This is the code I have right now

```
z := html.NewTokenizer(body)    

for{
    tt := z.Next()

    if tt= html.ErrorToken{
        return
    }
    else if tt== html.StartTagToken{
        tag := z.Token()

        if tag.Data =="h1"{
            fmt.Println("We found the title\n")
            //some code to find what is stored in the heading
        }
    }
}
```

How do I go about doing that?

EDIT: More specifically, what is the property of variable tag which would give me the text inside of it. I may be wrong with the conceptual terms here. Please bear with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you got is the `StartTagToken`, the part you're intrested in is between it and the corresponding `EndTagToken` as `TextToken`. So you need to read the next token and it's `Data` should be the value you're after, something like

```
...
if tag.Data =="h1"{
   if tt = z.Next(); tt == html.TextToken {
       fmt.Println(z.Token().Data)
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was perfect.